# If I install Django CMS will it still show my current work in Django admin

Tags: python, django

I'm totally new to Python and I've been learning how to use Django and it's admin functionality to work with my models. My question really is how, if I were to install Django CMS, would work with the admin?

My understanding it limited so I wanted to check as I'm struggling to know if it will still show the model's that I've been making in the same /admin/ url (as i read you login to the cms part via the /admin/ url).

Would installing the CMS overwrite anything current in my /admin/ view, or would the data management merely appear within the CMS control panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Django CMS is a totally different environment. You can't install it on top of your current project. So if you want your models inside django cms you have to migrate them manually to the new enviroment. Maybe their are solutions for it but I'm not aware of them.

Comment: Ahh ok I'm with you. Do you know if it's a similar setup process to import models etc into Django CMS as per admin? I will start read up on it now. Thank you.